# Über theorem on unavoidable patterns?

Tags: co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids, algebraic-combinatorics, symbolic-dynamics, combinatorics-on-words

Let $A$ be an alphabet of $k$ symbols,
and $p$ a *pattern*.
An example of a pattern is $p=XX$, where $X$ is any finite
string of symbols from $A^+$.
Avoiding $p$ is avoiding any subword repeated twice in a row.
Such strings are called *[square-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_word)*.

It is well known that there are no infinite binary ($k=2$) strings
of symbols that are square-free
(in fact, only $0$, $1$, $01$, $10$, $010$, and $101$ are square-free),
but there are infinite ternary ($k=3$) square-free strings,
as proved by Axel Thue.

Other examples:
[the patterns $X$ and $XYX$ are unavoidable on any alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoidable_pattern#Examples).

My question is:

> **Q**. Is there a theorem of the form: Any alphabet $A$ with $|A| \le k$
>   cannot avoid any patterns $p$ of the form [some description of these patterns $p$
>   as a function of $k$],
>   i.e., there are no infinite strings that avoid these $p$?

In other words, is there a pattern to—a characterization of—the patterns that are unavoidable,
for a given $k$? Or are there, to date, only claims that
specific patterns are unavoidable?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93997/avoidable-words is relevant, if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the 2013 paper ["Computing the Partial Word Avoidability Indices of
Ternary Patterns"](https://www.uncg.edu/cmp/research/patterns2/TernaryPatterns.pdf) by Blanchet-Sadri, Lohr, and Scott,

> The problem of deciding whether a given pattern is avoidable has been
>   solved [1, 14], but the one of deciding whether it is k-avoidable has remained
>   open.

So, it seems to be an open problem.

Comment: Thanks, Bjørn! [14] is Zimin's 1984 paper. Apparently Zimin characterized unavoidable patterns. But as you indicate, without restriction to $k$ symbols.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke An interesting factoid that you didn't mention is that the famous Thue-Morse word 01101001... avoids the pattern XYXYX, and such words are called "overlap-free" (or "irreducible" or "strongly cube-free") because any overlap of a word with itself would have to follow such a pattern.

Comment: The English language does not consist of irreducible words only, however, as there is "alfalfa".

Comment: Great example! Maybe *entente* qualifies as an overlap word, but it is really French (cf. détente). Surely overlap words exist in many languages...